# How to get if an value is inside of an array in a request in Laravel 6 blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form where you can check filters which will later filter a search query. The form is working but I would love to mark the checked checkboxes after the request as checked that the user can see what he selected.

It's working with one checkbox but if I add an array it's not working anymore.

````
   <input type="text" class="form-control bg-transparent border-0 searchbox" placeholder="{{ __('general.search_placeholder') }}" value="{{ app('request')->input('q') }}" name="q" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
   <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn border-0 searchbox" type="submit " id="button-addon2"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
   </div>
   @foreach($collections as $collection)
   <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$collection->id}}" name="s[]" id="defaultCheck{{$collection->id}}" {{ app('request')->input('s') == $collection->id ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck{{$collection->id}}">
      {{$collection->id}}
      </label>
   </div>
   @endforeach
</form>```


Does anybody know how to solve that?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s[]` is an array of checked checkboxes, you could use `in_array` to test if the current `$collection->id` is in there:

```
{{ in_array($collection->id, app('request')->input('s')) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```